# ImportError upon executing exabgp command

Tags: python, bgp

I am currently using Centos 7 and Python 2.7.5. I installed exabgp 4.0 and python2-exabgp rpms. but as soon as I execute exabgp command I get ImportError:

```
    [root@~]# exabgp -version
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/sbin/exabgp", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('exabgp==4.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'exabgp')()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 378, in load_entry_point
         return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2566, in load_entry_point
         return ep.load()
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2260, in load
         entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(),     ['__name__'])
    ImportError: No module named exabgp.application
```

Comment: How did you install it? `pip`? `easy-install`?